# R - Go to next step in loop when error

Tags: r, for-loop

I am running simulations in R, in a *for* loop. In each step of the loop, I am trying to fit a beta binomial distribution using the *vglm* function of the **VGAM** package:

```
vglm(data ~ 1, betabinomial)
```

However, for some of my generated data, a beta binomial model will not fit and the function crashes. Because it crashes, R exits the loop and stops. I would like to simply move to the next step in the loop. I am aware of the function *tryCatch* but have failed to use it in my case.
At the moment, my code is as follows (note that the *for* loop is nested in another *for* loop):

```
for (i in 1:nsimu) {
    ## Some code to generate Pos and Neg
    data <- cbind(Pos,Neg)
    if (sum(Pos)==0) {
       ##Go to next step
    } 
    else { 
       vglm(data ~ 1, betabinomial)
    } 
}
```

Thank you very much for any help or suggestion.

Stéphane

Answer (score 6):

You can use `next` to skip a step in a `for` loop :

```
R> for (i in 1:5) { if (i==2) next(); print(i)}
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do

```
if (sum(Pos) > 0) 
  vglm(data ~ 1, betabinomial)
```

By design, R only runs the code on the next newline if the condition is evaluated `TRUE`. Always best to use curly braces `{}` to wrap the expression to avoid ambiguity though, and you can add an `else` condition to evaluate some other expression if `Pos==0`

```
if (sum(Pos) > 0){
  vglm(data ~ 1, betabinomial)
} else {
  do something else
}
```

Comment: @juba thanks. I'm wondering if a nested `for` loop is really necessary here.

Comment: Thanks to Simon and juba. However, my main problem is that there are cases when **sum(Pos) > 0** and the model still does not fit (and these are not determined by i, they are determined by the data, so I need to try and fit the model first). These are the cases I want to ignore.
As far as the nested *for* loop is concerned, it is for another parameter.